# Remotely accessing different services/machines on a network with single external IP without specifying ports in URL

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a home network with multiple PCs, a self-made NAS (OMV/Debian) and a RPi connected to my router. I have a domain registered at Namecheap.com and dynamic DNS set up. The NAS and the RPi both run file servers (RPi always on, NAS woken on demand), the NAS also runs a Web server, a Plex Media Server and hosts its config webpage. Each service has a unique port forward set up in the router.

So far I have to access all services by specifying the ports, e.g. mydomain.com:11443 for the config page, mydomain.com:11444 for the NAS file server, mydomain.com:11555 for the RPi file server etc.. I'd like to replace the port numbers by some name, I don't care if it's by subdomains (preferred) or something like mydomain.com/nas/web, mydomain.com/plex, mydomain.com/rpi/files/ and so on, whatever works.

I read everything I could find (found things like SRV records, IPv6, and mod_proxy) but none of those got me much further. I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One could modify their htaccess file `Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on rewriterule ^home(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/1234$1 [r=301,nc] `

Answer (score 0):

One could modify their htaccess file 
`Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on 
rewriterule ^home(.*)$ http://example.com:1234$1 [r=301,nc]`

Look into 301 redirects.

Comment: If I understand correctly I should 1. host an apache web server on my always-on RPi, 2. have my router port forward port 80 to the RPis local IP, 3. add the `.htaccess` file to the server and 4. add an entry like the one you posted for every subdomain/port pair.  That way I enter the subdomain URL, the server responds with the domain:port and my browser/app goes there. Does it work for protocols other then http like ftp and ssh?

Comment: Basically yes, your using a front-end web-server to redirect the traffic. Technically this normally would be done with routers but from your specific setup .htaccess will suffice. (Unless your sitting on a cisco nexus that you haven't told us about)

Comment: Unfortunately not, just the one my ISP provided. It can't even update my DDNS reliably so I have to run `ddclient` on the RPi. What about ftp and ssh requests, will they also be redirected or only http?

Comment: FTP and SSH for the vast majority manually enter their port numbers in their clients or they host on standard numbers. Example ftp:21 leaving the program to assume the port.

Comment: It would be nice to have it accessible by name only since I can't always use standard ports due to running services multiple times (e.g. ftp/ssh on RPi for high demand files, NAS for large files). My regular machines can save the ports, but I also need files on e.g. business trips. I guess I can do most things via http, so knowing how to get that working is a huge step forward, thanks a lot!

Comment: @bjoern Your welcome, good luck!